# How to solve error: Unexpected value 'AppModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use **ng-sort** in my angular project, but I facing this error

> Unexpected value 'AppModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

my code in **app.module.ts**

```
...
import { AppModule as SortModule } from 'ng-sort';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LogInComponent,
    HomeComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    SortModule, 
...       
  ],
  providers: [ThemeService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

also, I did it in my **clients-mod.module** because I use lazy loading

```
...
import { AppModule as SortModule } from 'ng-sort';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainClientComponent,
    ClientInfoComponent,
    ClientDetailComponent,
    ClientsAccComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
...

    SortModule

  ]
})
export class ClientsModModule { }
export class AppModule {

}
```

Give some suggestions to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two suggestions: `1` : Remove `export class AppModule` from `client-mod.module`  and `2.` Provide screenshot of error.  Let me know once it is done

Comment: Also, confirm if you have done `npm install` for `ng-sort`

Comment: why are you doing this? import { AppModule as SortModule } from 'ng-sort';

Comment: @pixelbits; I do it because this is one of the usage steps as per NPM [https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-sort/v/0.1.18]

Comment: @ Shashank Vivek: I face the same error after I removed export class AppModule:![https://www14.0zz0.com/2019/10/29/16/269089682.png] and yes install was done

Comment: @ Shashank Vivek: I tried many times to attach a link of screenshot but didn't work try this one **_https://i.ibb.co/L5v1L2F/Capture.png_**